# CoreData error by saving new item to filtered fetch request with inheritance

Tags: swift, core-data

I have set up my Core Data model with entity inheritance (A is parent entity of X and Y). By doing the fetch request I have a predicate to filter a property of a child entity (X).

That is my fetch request:

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "A")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "test == %@", "123")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
    return fetchRequest
}
```

Note: "test" is an attribute of X.

Now when I'm trying to add a new child item (of type Y), my app crashes an throws the following error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  [<...> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Y is not key value coding-compliant for the key "test". with userInfo { ... }
>   NSUnknownUserInfoKey = test;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested in a possible solution:
I've avoided that issue by deleting the fetchRequest predicate and creating my own filter function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the entity you are fetching ("A", and its subentities) and the predicate, which is testing an attribute which is present on only one of the subentities ("X").

All is fine while you have only "X"s, but as soon as you create a "Y" object, the FRC sees it, checks whether the entity matches its underlying fetch (which it does, since "Y" is a subentity of "A").  It then tests to see whether the "Y" object matches the predicate and finds that it doesn't have a `test` attribute.  Hence it throws the exception.

Since only "X" objects can match the predicate, you should amend the fetch to use the "X" entity:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "X")
```

Comment: In my request I'm fetching X entities as well as Y entities using the above predicate. That works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That error is typically due to a crash in an `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` or some observer of one of the Core Data changes.  You should add go to the breakpoint navigator (Command-7), click the little plus at the bottom of the breakpoint navigator area, and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint...".  This should cause the debugger to pause the app when the exception is thrown so you can see specifically which piece of code is having problems.

Comment: The debugger stops by saving the core data:
try managedObjectContext.save()